# How to not convert a string to 0 while user makes a wrong input in Ruby on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a model in which I want to validate number of tightenings which user made. It must be only a non-negative integer. The problem is that when I input a string, it automatically substitutes a string with 0 while saving before applying regular expression. How to force an input to be only a non-negative integer without converting a string to 0?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :number_of_tightenings, format: { with: /\A[0-9]+\z/,
    message: "You have to input a number >= 0." }
end
```

Comment: When you only want to store positive integers why do you want to store them as strings and try to validate them with a regex? When the column was an integer column then you could use Rails [numericality validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality).

Comment: I thought that it is impossible to resolve my problem with numericality validator, but reading it deeper I found that it is possible to do it with `validates :number_of_tightenings, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ActiveRecord's numericality validation. (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :number_of_tightenings,
    numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
end

# schema.rb
t.integer "number_of_tightenings"
```

`only_integer` specifies that it shoul indeet be a integer (not a float). `greater_than_or_equal_to` specifies that no negative integer is allowed.
This would generate the following behaviour:

```
User.create(number_of_tightenings: 4) #=> <User id: 8, number_of_tightenings: 4, created_at: "2020-12-16 12:03:47", updated_at: "2020-12-16 12:03:47">
User.create(number_of_tightenings: "5") #=> <User id: 6, number_of_tightenings: 5, created_at: "2020-12-16 11:54:39", updated_at: "2020-12-16 11:54:39">
User.create(number_of_tightenings: "-5") #=> <ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007faa18df2180 @base=#<User id: nil, number_of_tightenings: -5, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:number_of_tightenings=>["must be greater than or equal to 0"]}, @details={:number_of_tightenings=>[{:error=>:greater_than_or_equal_to, :value=>-5, :count=>0}]}>
User.create(number_of_tightenings: "test") #=> <ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007faa182836c8 @base=#<User id: nil, number_of_tightenings: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:number_of_tightenings=>["is not a number"]}, @details={:number_of_tightenings=>[{:error=>:not_a_number, :value=>"test"}]}>
```